# combining a php variable within html footer

Tags: html, variables

I have a php variable in my web application that is `$companyname`, this comes from a session variable elsewhere in the code which I know works by testing with a simple echo.

I have written my footer in HTML which is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<footer>
  <p>This information belongs to . $companyname . if you are not the intended recipient please contact the owner or send us an  <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">email </p>
  <p>All rights reserved 2015</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

I have never combined a variable within a html footer before, normally just use plain text with a hyperlink.  Obviously this isnt working because I dont know how I am doing this and have googled it without much success.

Can someone please tell me how to get the $companyname to actually display as a variable rather than the text, see picture [here](http://prntscr.com/7a4yuv).

Also if its not too much trouble, I would like the $companyname to be in bold

Comment: <?php echo $companyname; ?>

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML outside `<?php ... ?>` blocks. So basically outputting php variable in HTML would be:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<footer>
  <p>This information belongs to <?php echo $companyname; ?> if you are not the intended recipient please contact the owner or send us an  <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">email </p>
  <p>All rights reserved 2015</p>
</footer>

</body>
</html>
```

However You did not provide information how HTML is generated, so can't help here anymore.

Comment: Thanks thats worked, now looks like <p>This information belongs to <?php echo $_SESSION["companyname"] ?>, if you are not the...  However can someone tell me how to get the echo in bold please

Comment: bold is HTML tag, not php. `<p>This information belongs to <b><?php echo $_SESSION["companyname"] ?></b>, if you are not the...`

Comment: Thanks, this did the trick <?php Print "<strong>".$_SESSION["companyname"] ?>,

Comment: Ok one small problem, everything after the php variable is now bold, using  <p>This information belongs to <?php Print "<strong>".$_SESSION["companyname"] ?>, if you are not the intended recipient please contact the owner or send us an  <a href="mailto:someone@example.com">email </p>